# I am trying to add image in this list view

Tags: android, android-listview

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.offers);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String xml = XMLfunctions.getX## Heading ##ML();
    Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
    int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);
    if((numResults <= 0))
    {
        Toast.makeText(OffersActivity.this, "Geen resultaten gevonden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        finish();
    }
    ImageView newImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbimage);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
        map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
        map.put("name", "" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
        map.put("Score", "" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "score"));
        map.put("thumbnail", "" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "thumbimg"));
        mylist.add(map);
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.listitems, 
            new String[] { "name", "Score",  "thumbnail"}, 
            new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.thumbimage });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I have addresses of the images which i want to display are in

```
map.put("thumbnail", "" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "thumbimg"));
```

And i am also getting them. Actually they are coming from live xml. And i want to put them in a image view. Please help!

thanks

Comment: Yes this a good article. But in my case xml is on live server. i have get the text and also display it on listview. But not able to display relative images.

Comment: Check this link : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html.... You will get some idea to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the images in the background and then set them in the correct ImageViews.

The adapters don't give you all that functionality by default, so you'll have to do some extra coding yourself.

Take a look at this StackOverflow answer: [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012) and you'll see what I mean!

Comment: I am getting this in log

04-16 16:19:46.768: I/System.out(514): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: R.drawable.thmbimg

Comment: If i had to guess it looks like you're trying to load a local image through the lazyload code? Since it's not a remote image, it won't work in the same way. I think it's trying to parse the R.drawable.thmbimg as a URI and failing (which is normal, since it's not a URI, it's a local android thing).

Comment: I have done this.. But i got a problem.. Its working perfect in simulator but not in device. 

I have replace R.drawable.thmbimg with http://cards.designers99.com/thmbimg.png

Comment: What version of android is each one running?

Comment: i am doing development in 2.2 and device is 2.3.3. But i have check all API and methods they all supported for both.

Answer (score 1):

There is a List view named LazyListview.I think this will help you for sure.This Lazy List will help you to download the images in background.As you open the List Activity intialy you will see the the default image is loaded after downloading the image will be setting one by one which makes an awesome User Interface.

I think this [code](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) will help you a lot.... :-)